# Generate linear, exponential weights and the sum of both (sum of all = 1)

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

Hi I am trying to calculate linear, exponentian weights and a combination of both.

**Linear weights** are defined as:

$\sum_{i}^N w_i = w_1+w_2+...+w_N = 1$

***Example:***

```
A = 100, B = 50, C = 400

weight_A = 100/550 = 18%
weight_B = 50/550 = 9%
weight_C = 400/550 = 73%
```

**Exponential Weights:**

The weights should follow an exponential function $e^x$ and the weight should also sum up to 1:

$\sum_{i}^N w_i = \frac{w^{N-i}}{\sum_{i}^Nw^{N-i}} = 1$, $\forall$ $N = 1,...,n$

***Example:***

```
A = 100, B = 50, C = 400, Smoothening = 0.6, N = 3

weight_A = 100*0.6^(3-1)/494 = 11%
weight_B = 50*0.6^(2-1)/494 = 8%
weight_C = 400*0.6^(1-1)/494 = 81%
```

How would a combination of linear and exponential using the indicator function look like to get a sum of weight of 1. Is that possible and if yes is an example possible?

**Linear + Exponential:**

Using the linear weights from:

```
weight_A = 18%
weight_B = 9%
```

and the exponential weight from:

```
weight_C = 81%
```

because all values above **350** will be exponential weighted in this case C is **400** and therefore **> 350**. When summing it up, I would receive weights larger than **100%**.

I would expect doing the following:

$sum_{weights} = w_{A_{linear}}+w_{B_{linear}}+w_{C_{exponential}} = 125\%$

Then I normalize it by the sum of all weights:

$\frac{w_{A_{linear}}}{sum_{weights}} + \frac{w_{B_{linear}}}{sum_{weights}} + \frac{w_{C_{exponential}}}{sum_{weights}} = 100\%$

The main question is, whether this is the proper approach for all three ways determine weights?

Answer (score 1):

You have the linear weight $w^{(l)} = (w^{(l)}_k)$ with $\sum_k w^{(l)}_k = 1$ and the exponential weight $w^{(e)} = (w^{(e)}_k)$ with $\sum_k w^{(e)}_k = 1$.

How about
$$
w_k = W_1 w^{(l)}_k + W_2 w^{(e)}_k 
$$
for any $W_1$, $W_2$ with $W_1 + W_2 = 1$, which is a weight. :)
Then
$$
\sum_k w_k =
\sum_k \left( W_1 w^{(l)}_k + W_2 w^{(e)}_k \right) 
= W_1 \left( \sum_k w^{(l)}_k \right) + W_2 \left( \sum_k w^{(e)}_k \right)
= W_1 + W_2 
= 1
$$

**Example:**

If
$$
W_1 = 1/3, W_2 = 2/3
$$
then
$$
w_k = \frac{1}{2} w^{(l)}_k + \frac{2}{3} w^{(e)}_k 
$$
should do the job.

Comment: thanks a lot. But do you have an example.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you make the example using the numbers given above from my two exaples?

Comment: what I mean lets say from my example above, everything what is above 350 should be exponential and below linear. Which weights should I use to get at the end as sum 1. what should happen is that the weighted sum of Ab,B and C should still be 550 and the sum of weights 1. Clearer?

Comment: I do not understand what "above 350" means, because I lack your context. Is this from some data smoothing task? Where did you get the definition of the exponential weights from?

Comment: I extended my description above. Hope that helps more?